# How to know Hadoop reducer assigned records

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using custom partitioner that assign records to the reducers randomly. Then the reducers start processing.

Is there a way I can know how many records assigned to each reducer before the reducers start working??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitioner does not assign records to the reducer randomly ,it has predefined logic

when we write custom partitioner we write the logic how records should be distributed among reducers

for instance if you are dealing with the data with consists of one field age

You can decide how your input would be processed at reducer

first of all you would have to configure no. of reducer you want for particular job which can configured in driver program of map reduce job

suppose you have configured 3 number of reducer .

While writing custom partitioner you would define the logic for instance

```
       if(ageInt <=20){               
            return 0;
        }
        //else if the age is between 20 and 50, assign partition 1
        if(ageInt >20 && ageInt <=50){

            return 1 % numReduceTasks;
        }
        //otherwise assign partition 2
        else
            return 2 % numReduceTasks;
```

All those records which falls in the category to less than age 20 would go to first reducer .

Even before executing job you can count all number of records based on your condition.

Comment: Thanks, your reply was the breakthrough.